# Unexpectedly high running time when using an orchestrating lambda function to call other lambda functions asynchronously

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that is to be invoqued by an orchestrating lambda function.
The orchestrating lambda function needs to asynchronously call this sub function 250 times each time with a different input string. The strings are stored in an s3 bucket.
**When I call the sub-function to run individually, its funning time takes 4 seconds.**
**But when I use the orchestrating lambda function the whole process takes 3 minutes.**

**Since the 250 functions are being called asynchronously I would expect the running time to still be around 4 seconds. What am I doing wrong ? Code of the orchestrating function bellow.**

```
import boto3
import json


lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')

#auxiliary function to invoque the other lambda functions
def invoke_lambda_function(name, input_data):

    response = lambda_client.invoke(
        FunctionName=name,
        #InvocationType='RequestResponse',
        InvocationType='Event',  # Asynchronous invocation
        Payload=input_data
    )
    
    x = json.loads(input_data)


def read_json_from_s3(bucket_name, file_key):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_key)
    json_data = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
    return json.loads(json_data)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    #getting avaliable symbols
    bucket_name = 'testbucket'
    file_key = 'avaliable_strings.json'
    strings_to_use = read_json_from_s3(bucket_name, file_key)
    
    #invoque one function per symbol
    invoked_functions = []
    function_name = "SubLambdaFucntion"  
    for s in strings_to_use:
        function_input = {'string' : s}
        function_input = json.dumps(function_input)
        invoke_lambda_function(name = function_name, input_data = function_input)
```

Comment: *Since the 250 functions are being called asynchronously I would expect the running time to still be around 4 seconds.* - why? Running something in 250 copies, means 250 times the load for every single component involved. Even though some parts are just waiting (and 250\*0 is still 0), other parts are doing actual work.